# How to control 2 light sources glare in one composite image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, compositing-nodes

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXenw.png

How can I rework this node system in the compositor so I can have the glare be different for two different objects emitting light within a single image render?